# Radio buttons group XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, radio-button

I have six radio buttons in XAML, and I would like to create two groups. It seems that WPF has no radiobutton group element, so how can I do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to specify a GroupName for the element.

```
 <RadioButton GroupName="Group1"/>
```

Answer (score 13):

BitKFu's suggestion of using the `GroupName` property will work, but there is a caveat. If you use group names, the scope for `RadioButton` groups becomes different.

If you create a `UserControl` with 3 `RadioButtons` all with a `GroupName` of `"MyRadioGroup"` and place 2 such controls in your `Window`, you will notice that all 6 `RadioButton`s act like they are one group.

This happens because when the `RadioButton` is updating other `RadioButton`s it normally only adjusts `RadioButton`s that are children of its immediate parent `DependencyObject`. However, when the `GroupName` is used the scope expands to the root `Visual` (`Window`, for example) and it will adjust all `RadioButton`s under that root that have the same `GroupName`.

So sometimes it's better to just separate them with an extra panel.