# Radio Button Group in a ListView's DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, .net-4.0

The question I have is an extension of the following answer.  It states that a radio button's GroupName has a very wide scope, and that often it is best to just let the GroupName be automatically assigned by the container.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6062697/907920

If I use a static GroupName, then all of the RadioButtons share the group.  (As the answer in the link indicated.)

However, if I don't use a GroupName, then each individual RadioButton is treated as if it were in a group by itself.  I can only assume that it is using the DataTemplate or the CellTemplate as it's 'parent' for the sake of automatically assigning the GroupName.

I have a list of Questions in a StackPanel.  Each Question is displayed in a UserControl.  Each Question contains a ListView of Answers.  Each Answer has a boolean property that indicates the answer has been selected, which binds to a RadioButton inside of a DataTemplate.

My stripped down XAML follows

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AnswerList}" >
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <!-- Other columns here -->
          <GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=AnswerChecked}" />
              </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

I don't think that I have any other option but to use the ListView, since I need to be able to turn the other columns off and on, as well as the need to display two or more answers.

Is there a way for me to tell the radio button that it is part of the UserControl and not the DataTemplate for the purposes of its GroupName?

I considered assigning a GUID to each UserControl and binding the RadioButtons's GroupName to the GUID's string, but that seems excessive and clumsy.

Edit: For visual reference, the UI flows *about* like this, my notes in parenthesis:

(StackPanel of Questions bound to a collection of Questions)

1. Question Control (Contains a ListView bound to a collection of Answers '|' delimits columns)

   - [ ] |  Answer 1 (Unchecked Answer Object with text "Answer 1")
   - [ ] |  Answer 2
   - [*] |  Answer 3 (Checked Answer Object with text "Answer 3")
2. Who was the 16th President

   - [ ] |  Karl Marx
   - [*] |  Abraham Lincoln
   - [ ] |  Richard Nixon
3. What is the weight of one mole of Hydrogen

   - [ ] |  10g
   - [ ] |  .1g
   - [ ] |  1g

Comment: "I considered assigning a GUID to each UserControl and binding the RadioButtons's GroupName to the GUID's string, but that seems excessive and clumsy."  -- Also it did not work.  I ended up with the same issue as before.  Every RadioButton was treated as independent of the others.

Comment: Seems like I'm barking up the wrong tree with this.  Radio Buttons (at least in 4.5) will be automatically be grouped by their container.

Answer (score 3):

you should be able to get away with something like this

```
 <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=AnswerChecked}" />
```

This should group them all together.

If the ListView is part of the QuestionControl why not bind the QuestionText as the questions should be unique

```
<RadioButton GroupName="{Binding Path=TheQuestionText}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=AnswerChecked}" />
```

you may have to use `FindAncestor` to access your `Questioncontrol` from the `DataTemplate`

```
 <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type QuestionControl}}, Path=QuestionText"}  />
```

Comment: This causes all of the RadioButtons across the Question controls to be treated as part of one group.  What I need is for the RadioButtons each Question control to be treated as one group, separate from the other RadioButtons in the other Question controls.

Comment: ahh.. I'm having trouble understanding how your layout fits together, could you post a screenshot perhaps?

Comment: Could you not just use the Question text as the RadioButtons group name as the questions should be unique?

Comment: The question text isn't guaranteed to be unique, but they do have unique Ids.  Binding the Group Name to the unique Id caused each radio button to act as if they were in a group of 1.

Answer (score 0):

This got me past my impasse, but I will not accept it.  This solution is far from optimal.

I switched over to using a CheckBox, and in the VM I added this code to the Answer's PropertyChanged callback, and I added a Property "AllowAnswer" to the Answer Object.

```
    void AnswerItemChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    if (e.PropertyName == "AnswerChecked")
    {
        bool hasAnswer = false;
        foreach(Answer answer in Answers)
        {
            if (answer.AnswerChecked == true)
            {
                hasAnswer = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        foreach (Answer answer in Answers)
        {
            substep.PropertyChanged -= AnswerItemChanged;

            if (hasAnswer && !answer.AnswerChecked )
            {
                answer.AllowAnswer = false;
            }
            else 
            {
                answer.AllowAnswer = true;
            }

            substep.PropertyChanged += AnswerItemChanged;
        }
    }
    }
```

This allows the CheckBox to ape the mutex functionality of the RadioButton.  However, it's much more kludgy in practice as the user will now have to de-select an answer to select another one.